# Referring to c# objects in JSON

Tags: c#, json, object

I have two JSON files. One which contains info about a player and the other about his team.
I deserialized the team JSON file in C# and made a team object. In the player class, there is a property 'teamassigned' in which I want the value to be the team object I made earlier, but I want to store it in a JSON file.

JSON For Driver

```
{
    "driverName": "Esyltt Aviars",
    "teamAssigned": TEAM OBJECT HERE,
    "DefendingScore": 47,
    "BrakingScore": 80,
    "CorneringScore": 38,
    "RaceStartScore": 92,
    "ConsistencyScore": 74,
    "FocusScore": 55 
}
```

JSON For Team

```
{
    "teamID": 1,
    "teamName": "Mclaren",
    "teamColor": "orange"
}
```

Comment: if there is no way to do this then can you please suggest some way to store info like this cause I have around 12 teams and 24 drivers

Comment: You'll just have to use nested JSON objects; https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Show us your C# classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in following way:

Your Classes for Player & Team will be:

```
public class Team  
{
     public int teamID { get; set; } 
     public string teamName { get; set; } 
     public string teamColor { get; set; }    
}    
public class Player
{
     public string driverName { get; set; } 
     public Team teamAssigned { get; set; } 
     public int DefendingScore { get; set; } 
     public int BrakingScore { get; set; } 
     public int CorneringScore { get; set; } 
     public int RaceStartScore { get; set; } 
     public int ConsistencyScore { get; set; } 
     public int FocusScore { get; set; } 
}
```

When deserialize the data of these classes, the resultant Json would be:

```
{
    "driverName": "Esyltt Aviars",
    "team": {
    "teamID": 1,
    "teamName": "Mclaren",
    "teamColor": "orange"
      },
    "DefendingScore": 47,
    "BrakingScore": 80,
    "CorneringScore": 38,
    "RaceStartScore": 92,
    "ConsistencyScore": 74,
    "FocusScore": 55 
}
```

**Updated Answer As Required**

Above two classes Player and Team are used to deserialize Json data to objects, as given below:

```
var objPlayer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(playerJson);
var objTeam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Team>(teamJson);
```

As a result got data in two objects. Now assign both objects data to a new object of type **Player** along with assign values of object **Team** to the field "teamAssigned", as given below:

```
var objMerged = new Player()
{
    driverName = objPlayer.driverName,
    teamAssigned = new Team() 
                   { 
                     teamID = objTeam.teamID,
                     teamName = objTeam.teamName, 
                     teamColor = objTeam.teamColor 
                   },
    DefendingScore = objPlayer.DefendingScore,
    BrakingScore = objPlayer.BrakingScore,
    CorneringScore = objPlayer.CorneringScore,
    RaceStartScore = objPlayer.RaceStartScore,
    ConsistencyScore = objPlayer.ConsistencyScore,
    FocusScore = objPlayer.FocusScore,
};
```

Now, serialze this object "objMerged" to Json as:

```
var convertToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objMerged);
```

The resultant Json in "convertToJson" will be as per requirement with property 'teamassigned' having the value to be the team object.

Comment: Ahh I think I didn't ask the question properly. I already have the teams object setup. As in there is an object for it. The team object is deserialized from  a seperate json file.

Comment: Do you want to include Team Json object in Player Json object, where Team object will be assigned to 'teamassigned'?

Comment: Yes exactly. The team json file is deserialized before player json is.

Comment: @KevTech if my answer worked for you, kindly marked it as answer and up-vote.